# How to automate time series analysis/monitor (descriptive)?

Tags: time-series, python, predictive-models, descriptive-statistics

For example, here is a traffic graph from google analytics:

[image]

You can see that first there is a spike, and then a long plateau time, and then increase to a slightly high stage (but more volatile), and then drop down to 0.

My question: is it possible to **detect/describe them when they occur**?

Specifically, to automatically tell me:

- Is there any stable trend recently?
- Is there any spike/drop down recently?
- Is there any upward/doward trend recently?

For example, at 2018 Aug, it tells me there is a spike, and at 2018 Oct, tells me there is new stable trend, and a Feb 2019 tells me that it might enter a higher-level with more volatility.

Reasons for doing this: we might have many time series to watch, so we can automate some simple/obvious tasks.

How can I do it? is there any related Python/R packages? (maybe like https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling )

---

I think it's possible.

- We may need to handcode what is stable/spike/dropdown, specify the significant level. and determine the window size.
- A naive approach can be using predictive time series packages like `Facebook Prophet`, and send alert when time series is not aligned with the prediction.

Comment: Look at the differences between consecutive values.

Comment: if you post your data in a csv file i will try and help you https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380599/is-it-possible-to-automate-time-series-forecasting/380634#380634 is where you should start

Comment: @DemetriPananos Great insight! and how should I determine window size? and is there any related doc/paper/blog? and how can I detect trend/seasonal effect?

Comment: @cqcn1991 I can't offer a one size fits all solution, but you should be able to detect periodic behavior via FFT.

Comment: @DemetriPananos you mean something like seasonal decomposition, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/28284962/1794744 ?